# insert array into mysql (userCake)

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, pdo, sql-insert

I am building a website on the userCake source code. At this moment I have an array that I want to insert into my MySQL database.

I get the data for my array from a form. This is the code that builds the array:

```
$pauzes = array();
    foreach($users as $usr)
    {
      $pauzes = array_merge($pauzes, array(
        $usr['username'] => $_POST[$usr['username']]));
    }
```

When I call print_r($pauzes) after this code, a possible output could be:

> Array ( [jules] => 12.30-13.00 [marc] => 12.30-13.00 [nick] =>
>   13.30-14.00 [paulo] => --- [kevin] => --- [rick] => --- [sanam] => --- [yvette] => --- [bas] => --- [bruce] => --- )

('---' means that no time is selected)

The way userCake works I will have to use bind_param, but I cannot send an array (???)
I found some code how to get the data from the array, so the output then should be something like username-time

This is the function the should write the data to the database:

```
function add_pauze($datum, $pauzes)
{
    GLOBAL $mysqli, $db_table_prefix;

    // array $pauzes opdelen in aparte stukken zodat deze kan worden opgeslagen in de database
    if(is_array($pauzes))
    {
        $data = array();
        foreach($pauzes as $row){
                $naam = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli,$row['username']);
                $tijd = mysqli_real_escape_string($mysqli, $row['tijd'] );
                $data[] = "($naam', '$tijd')";
        }
    }
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO " . $db_table_prefix . "pauzes
                                                        (
                                                        datum,
                                                        gegevens
                                                        )
                                                        VALUES
                                                        " . implode(',', $data) ."
                                                        ");
    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $datum, $naam, $tijd);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    return($result);
}
```

When I try to insert data now, I get several warnings with Illegal String Offset. I believe this is because $naam ($row['username']) and $tijd ($row['tijd']) are not defined in the array?

I tried changing the code where i build the array to something like this:

```
$pauzes = array();
    foreach($users as $usr)
    {
      $pauzes = array_merge($pauzes, array(
        "username" => $usr['username'] , "tijd" => $_POST[$usr['username']]));
    }
```

But then my array isn't right anymore:

> Array ( [username] => bruce [tijd] => --- )

So now I am wondering how I can insert my array (right one is on top of this post) into my database.

Thanks in advance!

**--- Updated info ---**

I changed the code where I build my array:

```
$pauzes = array("user" => array(), "pauze" => array());
    foreach($users as $usr)
    {
      array_push($pauzes['user'], $usr['username']);
      array_push($pauzes['pauze'], $_POST[$usr['id']]);

    }
```

when I do print_r($pauzes), the output is:

> Array ( [user] => Array ( [0] => jules [1] => marc [2] => nick [3] =>
>   paulo [4] => kevin [5] => rick [6] => sanam [7] => yvette [8] => bas
>   [9] => bruce ) [pauze] => Array ( [0] => 13.30-14.00 [1] => --- [2] =>
>   --- [3] => 13.00-13.30 [4] => --- [5] => 12.00-12.30 [6] => --- [7] => --- [8] => --- [9] => --- ) )

The function add_pauze is updated and looks like this:

```
function add_pauze($datum, $pauzes)
{
    GLOBAL $mysqli, $db_table_prefix;

    // array $pauzes opdelen in aparte stukken zodat deze kan worden opgeslagen in de database
    if(is_array($pauzes))
    {
        $data = array();
        foreach($pauzes as $row){
                $naam = $row['user'];
                $tijd =  $row['pauze'];
                $data[] = "('$naam', '$tijd')";
        }
    }
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO " . $db_table_prefix . "pauzes
                                                        (
                                                        datum,
                                                        naam,
                                                        tijd
                                                        )
                                                        VALUES
                                                        " . implode(',', $data) ."
                                                        ");

    $stmt->bind_param("ss", $datum, $naam, $tijd);
    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    return($result);
}
```

when I echo the sql statement in this function, the output is:

> INSERT INTO applepauzes ( datum, naam, tijd ) VALUES ('', ''),('', '')

this because the **user** and **pauze** index are unidentified.

The columns I have in my database for the table applepauzes are:

1. id
2. datum
3. naam
4. tijd

in *naam* the name of the user needs to be stored.
in *tijd* the time of the break (pauze) needs te be stored.

as asked in the comments, when I do print_r($datum), the output is:

> 2015-02-21 (current date when writing)

Comment: Hi, have you tried to check SQL string you produce at the end of your process? You can get more information about what's happening by trying that sql sentence directly on your db. Another thing I would try using an if statement temporarily and fill the timings 00:00 - 00:00 if it is empty. So I could see the exact problem. I think you will achieve a better perspective of your problem if you be sure about your array + your sql sentence created.

Comment: It uses `mysqli` not `PDO`. The two are very different.

Comment: @SühaBoncukçu - the sql statement returns the name twice and the time twice and wants to insert that into the database. I also changed array_merge to array_push, do you know if that is a good idea?

Comment: You actually have quite a few problems here... you are confused on a number of things. What does `print_r($datum)` look like? What columns does the table `pauzes` have? What data needs to be inserted and to which columns? I can tell you how to fix this but i need to know those things in order to give you a working example and explain it.

Comment: @Jules, array_merge and array_push do not work in the same way. So I think this is not a good idea. However, according to syntax you use, all pairs should be created with two vars. As (datum1,gegevens1), (datum2, gegevens2),... . If one of them is not matching with the column list; it will throw an error according to here: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert.html which says: "The following statement is illegal because the number of values in the list does not match the number of column names:" I am sorry that I can't help more but the question really needs more clarifications.

Comment: @SühaBoncukçu - you're right, I had an error in my sql statement, but I corrected the statement with the same result for now

Comment: Right now, to clarify, you can think your pauzes array includes two arrays named username and pauze. If I were you, I would consider creating my array other way around, as Pauzes = ([0] => array('username' => usernameX, 'pauze' => pauzeX, 'tijd' => tijdX), [1]=>... ) and update the line $data[] = "('$naam', '$tijd')"; to have three vars including datum. In this way, it seems that it would work. Don't forget that your variable count should match with your column count in sql statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, first of all you are using a prepared statement but binding your values incorrectly. The SQL you give to `mysqli::prepare` should look like:

```
INSERT INTO applepauzes (datum, naam, tijd) VALUES (?,?,?)
```

With the `(?,?,?)` repeated for every user. Then you use `mysqli::bind_param` to bind the data to those values. Unfortunately `mysqli::bind_param` makes you bind them all at once and takes a variable number of arguments - one for each param to be bound, and they have to be by reference which makes it even more annoying.

So let's get to your data... What we will eventually need in order to run the SQL statement is an array that looks like this:

```
Array(
  0 => '2015-02-21',
  1 => 'juels',
  2 => '12.30-13.00',
  3 => '2015-02-21',
  4 => 'marc',
  5 => '12.30-1:00'
  // repeat for each user in the same order
)
```

However in order to craft the query properly we need to have things organized like:

```
Array (
   0 => array(
      0 => '2015-02-21',
      1 => 'juels',
      2 => '12.30-13.00'
   ),
   1 => array(
      3 => '2015-02-21',
      4 => 'marc',
      5 => '12.30-1:00'
   ),
   // repeat for every user record
)
```

I assume that `$_POST` looks something like:

```
Array(
   'juels' => '12.30-13.00',
   'marc' => '12.30-13.00',
   // etc
)
```

So the first thing we need to do is organize this properly:

```
$pauzes = array();
foreach ($users as $u) {
   $username = $u['username'];
   // if a user has an entry in the Form then add it to 
   // $pauzes array for insert into the DB
   if (isset($_POST[$username]) {
      // even though we want numeric keys eventually we
      // we will use the field names here so that its not ambiguous
      // later and we can easily reorder them
      $pauzes[] = array(
          'naam' => $username,
          'tijd' => $_POST[$username]
      )
   }
}

// call out function
add_pauzes(date('Y-m-d'), $pauzes);
```

So now we get to the heart of the matter... The actual insert with `mysqli`:

```
// add an array typehint so that the function
// only takes an array
function add_pauze($datum, array $pauzes)
{
    GLOBAL $mysqli, $db_table_prefix;

    // first we need to prepare our base array structure
    $records = array();
    $params = array();
    
    foreach ($pauzes as $pauze) {
        $prefix = $pauze['username'];
        // give the items unique keys so we can reference them 
        // in the flat array $params
        $records[$prefix] = array(

           $prefix . 'datum' => $datum,
           $prefix . 'naam' => $pauze['username'],
           $prefix . 'tijd' => $pauze['tijd']
        );

        
        $params = array_merge($params, $records[$prefix]);
    }

    print_r($params);

    // get our total number of records for insertion
    // eg. each array in $records represents a set of values
    // for a db record in the table
    $recordCount = count($records);

    // create placeholders (?,?,?), one for each $record element
    $placeholders = array_fill(0, $recordCount, '(?,?,?)');

    // create the SQL string for our insert using
    // sprintf will substitute our the %s for the other arguments
    // we give it...    
    $sql = sprintf(
        'INSERT INTO %spauzes (datum, naam, tijd) VALUES %s',   
        $db_table_prefix,
        implode(',', $placeholders)
    );

    // prepare out statmement
    $stmt = $mysqli->prepare($sql);

    // we have to use references to bind the params
    // and to make it easy we want to do so with call_user_func_array
    // so establish an array of arguments the first being the param
    // type and then so loop over $params and assign the values to
    // $args by reference
    $args = array(str_repeat('s', count($params)));
    foreach ($params as $k => &$v) {
        $args[$k] = &$v;
    }

    // bind all of our params using a callable and an array
    // of arguments to be passed into that callable
    call_user_func_array(array($stmt, 'bind_param'), $args);

    $result = $stmt->execute();
    $stmt->close();
    
    return $result;
}
```

Comment: With a few changes,your code is working. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Updated with changes. Tested locally and works. Also serves as a reminder to why I abhor `mysqli`.

Answer (score 0):

I solved my problem.

I changed the code where I build the array to:

```
$pauze_users = array("users" => array());
$pauze_tijd = array("tijd" => array());
foreach($users as $usr)
{
  array_push($pauze_users, $usr['username']);
  array_push($pauze_tijd, $_POST[$usr['id']]);

}
```

after that, I make sure that the data is right to place it in an SQL statement with this code:

```
$count_users = count($pauze_users);
$sql;
                for($i = 0; $i < $count_users; $i++)
                {
                    $sql .= "(" . $datum . ", " . $pauze_users[$i] . ", " . $pauze_tijd[$i] . ") ";     
        }
```

With this code, I will get an output like this:

> (2015-02-22, jules, 11.30-12.00) (2015-02-22, marc, 12.30-13.00)
>   (2015-02-22, nick, ---) (2015-02-22, paulo, 12.00-12.30) (2015-02-22,
>   kevin, ---) (2015-02-22, rick, ---) (2015-02-22, sanam, ---)
>   (2015-02-22, yvette, ---) (2015-02-22, bas, ---) (2015-02-22, bruce,
>   ---)

(I know that I will need to place << , >> between the data to make it acceptable for SQL

I want to thank you for the help to solve my problem!

Comment: Please see my answer... you leave yourself open to SQL injection here because you are not properly binding your parameters. My way is definitely more complicated but it is indeed worth it.

Comment: Correct, I have not yet secured the code against sql injection. This will be at a later stage. I got my code working now, but will take a look at your code in a minute. Thanks for taking the time to help me!

Comment: Other than very important injection problem @prodigitalson pointed , -according to my experience- using two different array with the same iterator usually causes pain in the future for scripting languages. You might want to reconsider reconstructing your array.

Comment: No worried... actually i jsut refactored it a bit to make sure it all worked and there is still the issue of passing by ref for bind_param.

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to INSERT an array (or any arbitrary PHP structure) into a MySQL table and be able to get it back out, then consider the following.  Note: You will not be able to easily inspect any of the array elements via SQL statement.

Add this to your table:

```
json TEXT NOT NULL COMMENT 'opaque array of stuff'
```

Use `json_encode($array)` to turn your array into a string, then INSERT that string into the `json` column.

After SELECTing the `json` column into `$json`, do this to get the array back:

```
$array = json_decode($json, true);
```